# Kubuntu wifi setup

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

Are 3 hours that I'm searching for kubuntu wifi setup and I can't find anything. The version of kubuntu is 21.10... Please... I really need help. The output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` is the following:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: ssb
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Let's start by determining if you have a device with a working driver. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: thank you so much!! It worked!!! Thank you!!!!